# CV state lead-acid battery charge from solar panel

Tags: battery-charging, pid-controller, lead-acid, solar-charge-controller, mppt

I simulate the charging of a lead-acid battery, using MPPT algorithms, Buck converter, a PID regulator and a solar panel. In the CC stage everything is perfect. The battery is charged up to 14.4V, so the output of the converter will have this value and we move to the CV stage. Perfect. The PID sees this voltage that must be maintained, and the resulting error is 0, resulting in a duty with a value of 0. The current starts to decrease and reaches 0.
In the CV stage, I don't understand how it should work. The solar panel is a source of current. How to maintain the voltage of 14.4V until the current drops naturally through the battery.

THX!
[image]

[image]
Vbat is divided by ten

time 68.5s: CC state stop, CV state start

The error will be 0 because the read voltage is 14.4V, it is equal to the reference, the duty starts to decrease, the current also decreases. stop condition Ibat<0.2A

Comment: Welcome! Please show simulation results. In CV phase, current isn’t zero so your duty cycle can’t be zero either. How are you modeling your battery?

Comment: There is no problem to make a voltage source from current source. Just switch the regulator from current-control loop to voltage-control loop.

Comment: the battery is from the SPS-lib library in simulink